# Making a discord chat bot and ran into this syntax error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.7

Here is my current problem. I usually don't ask and figure it out on my own, but my fellow developer is gone for the weekend and i can not figure this out.

```
 def acceptBattle(ctx,discord.Member,author.selectedPokemon,discord.Member.selectedPokemon):
        battleacc=input(bot.say(discord.Member +" "+ author +" has challenged you to a battle! Do you accept?"))
        conn = sqlite3.connect('BOT.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        part=c.execute("SELECT poke FROM Party WHERE id=="+author)
        pokemonteam1=part
        part2=c.execute("SELECT poke FROM Party WHERE id=="+discord.Member)
        pokemon2team=part2
        if(battleacc=='yes'or'y' or 'yeah'):
```

The Problem is at the this first part: "acceptBattle(ctx,discord.Member..."

Specifically the period(.) in discord.Member

Any ideas? appreciate any help

```
def CPokes(ctx,pokemon,message):
        caught=false
        run_away=false
        t=timer(3600,ifcaught)
        while  t>0:
                if run_away==false:
                        run=rand.randint(0,8)
                        if run==0:
                                run_away=true
                                break
                        else:
                                if message.contains('catch'):   
                                        msg=message.split
                                        conn = sqlite3.connect('blazidb.db')
                                        c = conn.cursor()
                                        pokename=c.execute("SELECT Identifier FROM Pokes WHERE numb==pokemon").fetchall()
                                        c.close()
                                        if pokename==msg[2]:
                                                caught=true
                                                randomstatsandNatures(pokemon)
                                                conn = sqlite3.connect('blazidb.db')

                                                break
                                        else:
                                                caught=false
    def Spawn(Pokes):
        spawned=rand.randint(1,807)
        conn = sqlite3.connect('blazidb.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        spn=c.execute("SELECT `Img AND Identifier FROM poke WHERE numb==spawned").fetchall()

        conn.close()
        bot.say("A Wild Pokemon Appeared!")
        CPokes(ctx,spn[1])
    def ifcaught():
        run_away=true
    def acceptBattle(ctx,discord.Member,author.selectedPokemon,discord.Member.selectedPokemon):
        battleacc=input(bot.say(discord.Member +" "+ author +" has challenged you to a battle! Do you accept?"))
        conn = sqlite3.connect('blazidb.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        part=c.execute("SELECT poke FROM Party WHERE id=="+author)
        pokemonteam1=part
        part2=c.execute("SELECT poke FROM Party WHERE id=="+discord.Member)
        pokemon2team=part2
        if(battleacc=='yes'or'y' or 'yeah'):
                poke1=author.selectedPokemon
                poke2=discord.Member.selectedPokemon
                BattlePokes(ctx,poke1,poke2,discord.Member,author)
                """BattlePokes(ctx,pokemonteam1,discord.Member,author,pokemonteam2)"""
        else:
```

Comment: The parameters you specify in the definition must be valid identifiers.  They are then used as the variable names for the passed values inside the function.  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: there is a bigger section..... its a pokemon bot. and this is the "spawning" and "battling" part for new pokemon spawning and the battle that happens if you try to catch one

Comment: my fellow developer wrote the code but unfortunately hes on a plane to india for the next 24 hours so i am trying to surprise him and take some of this bug fix load off of him

Comment: I am simply fixing syntax and indent problems.... and ran into this and it stumped me

Comment: As Patrick has mentioned, the parameters should be _valid identifiers_. `discord.Member` probably isn't one. Replace it (and other occurrences) with something like `member`, which you can then use. (Then you can also throw away the `discord.Member.selectedPokemon` parameter...)